# How can i display the next question in if-else statement after a user input the right one?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am experiencing an issue with if-else statements in my GUI project. The problem is that even when I input the correct password, it always considers the first input as incorrect when the button is clicked for the first time. However, when I input it for the second time, it is accepted.

```java
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            textArea.setVisible(true);
            b1.setVisible(false);
            tf.setVisible(true);
            b2.setVisible(true);
        } else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
            String userInput = tf.getText();
            String currentLine = lines[currentLineIndex];
            boolean isCorrect = false;

            if (currentLineIndex == 0 && userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("DARKNESS")) {
                isCorrect = true;
            } else if (currentLineIndex == 1 && userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("AGE")) {
                isCorrect = true;
            } else if (currentLineIndex == 2 && userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("ECHO")) {
                isCorrect = true;
            } else if (currentLineIndex == 3 && userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("GRUDGES")) {
                isCorrect = true;
            } else if (currentLineIndex == 4 && userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("SECRET")) {
                isCorrect = true;
            }

            if (isCorrect) {
                currentLineIndex++;
                if (currentLineIndex < lines.length) {
                    textArea.setText(lines[currentLineIndex]);
                    tf.setText("");
                } else {
                    b4.setVisible(true);
                    tf.setText("");
                    tf.setVisible(false);
                    b2.setVisible(false);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You completed all the riddles!");
                }
            } else {
                tf.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Incorrect answer");
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b4) {
                frame.dispose();
                new Frame10();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Step through it with a debugger. What is the value of `currentLineIndex` the first time through?

Comment: So, when _currentLineIndex_ is 1 it passes?

Comment: nope, when I input the "darkness" it automatically shows incorrect answer but if I input it again with the same input it accepts it

Comment: The definition and management of `currentLineIndex` seems like a critical part of this problem.  Consider adding this to the question.